# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, librosa

Using some code I found online, I successfully trained a model (whew!) to be able to tell if there is laughter in the audio file that I plug in.

This is the model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, BatchNormalization, Flatten

lr_model = Sequential()
# lr_model.add(keras.Input((None, 128)))
lr_model.add(BatchNormalization(input_shape=(10, 128)))
lr_model.add(Flatten())
lr_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
print(lr_model.summary())

# try using different optimizers and different optimizer configs
lr_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size=32

CV_frac = 0.1
train_gen = data_generator(batch_size,'.../Data/bal_laugh_speech_subset.tfrecord', 0, 1-CV_frac)
val_gen = data_generator(128,'.../Data/bal_laugh_speech_subset.tfrecord', 1-CV_frac, 1)

rec_len = 18768



lr_h = lr_model.fit(train_gen,steps_per_epoch=int(rec_len*(1-CV_frac))//batch_size, epochs=100, 
                       validation_data=val_gen, validation_steps=int(rec_len*CV_frac)//128,
                       verbose=1)
```

Then I wrote this code for plugging my audio file in.  It is similar to some code on detecting bat calls in an audio file.

```
soundarray, sr = librosa.load("video-1609522619.wav")
maxseconds = int(len(soundarray)/sr)
for second in range(maxseconds-1):
    audiosample = np.array(soundarray[second*sr:(second+1)*sr])
    print(audiosample)
    prediction = lr_model.predict(audiosample)
    
    if np.argmax(prediction)==1:
        IPython.display.display(IPython.display.Audio(audiosample, rate = sr,autoplay=True))
        librosa.output.write_wav('first_test.wav', audiosample, sr)
        
        time.sleep(2)
        print("hello")
        print("Detected laugh at " + str(second) + " out of " + str(maxseconds) + " seconds")
        print(prediction)
```

Then I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-0d974db166cf> in <module>
      4     audiosample = np.array(soundarray[second*sr:(second+1)*sr])
      5     print(audiosample)
----> 6     prediction = lr_model.predict(audiosample)
      7 
      8     if np.argmax(prediction)==1:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1627           for step in data_handler.steps():
   1628             callbacks.on_predict_batch_begin(step)
-> 1629             tmp_batch_outputs = self.predict_function(iterator)
   1630             if data_handler.should_sync:
   1631               context.async_wait()

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    860       # In this case we have not created variables on the first call. So we can
    861       # run the first trace but we should fail if variables are created.
--> 862       results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
    863       if self._created_variables:
    864         raise ValueError("Creating variables on a non-first call to a function"

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2939     with self._lock:
   2940       (graph_function,
-> 2941        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2942     return graph_function._call_flat(
   2943         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3355               self.input_signature is None and
   3356               call_context_key in self._function_cache.missed):
-> 3357             return self._define_function_with_shape_relaxation(
   3358                 args, kwargs, flat_args, filtered_flat_args, cache_key_context)
   3359 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _define_function_with_shape_relaxation(self, args, kwargs, flat_args, filtered_flat_args, cache_key_context)
   3277           expand_composites=True)
   3278 
-> 3279     graph_function = self._create_graph_function(
   3280         args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes=relaxed_arg_shapes)
   3281     self._function_cache.arg_relaxed[rank_only_cache_key] = graph_function

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3194     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3195     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3196         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3197             self._name,
   3198             self._python_function,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    988         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    989 
--> 990       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    991 
    992       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    632             xla_context.Exit()
    633         else:
--> 634           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    635         return out
    636 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /home/pete/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1478 predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /home/pete/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1468 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /home/pete/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /home/pete/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /home/pete/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/pete/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1461 run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    /home/pete/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1434 predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    /home/pete/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:998 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    /home/pete/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:219 assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError('Input ' + str(input_index) + ' of layer ' +

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1)
```

Which when I google around is usually an error for LSTM models.  But it's not.  Regardless, there's something weird going on with my input vs what is expected.

Here is my model summary:

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 10, 128)           512       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 1280)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 1281      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,793
Trainable params: 1,537
Non-trainable params: 256
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

I actually don't know why the BatchNormalization would have an `input_shape`.  Because isn't that just telling the model to batch a certain way?  Seems more like a setting than a layer...Is that part of the issue?  Anyways, that part is largely copied from someone who is more experienced than I and ultimately it worked, so I'm reluctant to mess around with it too much.

Comment: No, this error is not related to LSTM (so change your question title), the only problem is that you are missing the samples dimension set to one in your input. Just reshape audiosample to (1, 10, 128)

Comment: Provide the X_train.shape and Y_train.shape.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your input shape

**Working sample code snippet**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, BatchNormalization, Flatten
import tensorflow as tf

X_train = np.random.random((10,128))
y_train = np.random.random((10,1))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
train_data = dataset.shuffle(len(X_train)).batch(32)
train_data = train_data.prefetch(
        buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

lr_model = Sequential()
#lr_model.add(tf.keras.Input((10, 128)))
lr_model.add(BatchNormalization(input_shape=(128,)))
lr_model.add(Flatten())
lr_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
print(lr_model.summary())

lr_model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
                metrics=['accuracy'])

lr_model.fit(train_data, epochs=5)
```

**Output**

```
Model: "sequential_10"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 batch_normalization_6 (Batc  (None, 128)              512       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 flatten_8 (Flatten)         (None, 128)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_18 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 129       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 641
Trainable params: 385
Non-trainable params: 256
_________________________________________________________________
None
Epoch 1/5
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 673ms/step - loss: 0.8737 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 0.8573 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.8413 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 0.8256 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.8104 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```